# How to inspect global variables in GoLand when debugging a golang program?

Tags: debugging, go, goland

When I debug a go program in GoLand, I can't see the value of global variable. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Here is an example:

I set a breakpoint in the last line of main function. But as shown in the picture, we can only get the value of 'a', but not 'a' and 'xx'.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var xx int = 1

func main() {
    var a int = 1
    fmt.Println(a)
    xx = 3
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

[image]

Comment: The best way to fix it would be not to use global variables.

Answer (score 3):

We can use Evaluate function to get the value of global variables, but can only get one value each time

[image: evaluate]

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to show all global variables automatically. Just add them manually (by clicking plus sign or pressing <kbd>Insert</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

You can also right click the variable in the editor and "Add to Watches".

Answer (score 0):

visual code will show both local and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way. Just to elaborate more, you can click on Evaluate from Debug window:
[Evaluate Expression Button in Debug Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Am6.png)

Start typing the name of the variable, GoLand will try to autocomplete:
[Expression Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwFsE.png)

Then click on Evaluate button: [Autocompletion in Expression window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FrBT.png)